# What is the computational complexity of theorem proving?

Tags: foundations, computational-complexity

I heard theorem proving is a hard problem, hard enough that it contributed to an early [AI winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI_winter). *But how hard*?

While reading about proof assistants, I have come to realize that there are many types of theorem proving/logic behind: propositional logic, first-order (FOL), high-order (HOL), various type theories, and many others maybe.

My question is:

*What are the computational complexity (roughly speaking) for theorem proving for the different types of logic behind theorem provers?*

(e.g. undecidable, NP-hard, polynomial time etc.)

I just wanted to get a rough idea.

Comment: Basically, being undecidable is a **necessary** condition for it to be interesting.

Comment: Propositional calculus is a semi-exception, because it is so foundational. But it also have undecidable variants like full linear logic. Other decidable theories like highschool geometry is only of interest to algorithm optimization, not to geometry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Briefly:

**Propositional logic**: determining whether there is a proof is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard, since proving a formula entails determining that its negation is not satisfiable.

**First-order logic**: determining whether a proof exists is undecidable (Gödel's theorem).

**Type theory**: should also be undecidable since we can embed first-order logic in type theory.

Comment: Nice Answer! Small addition: you can also find NP-hard task in built-in DNF solver for cubical subsystems in cubical type checkers.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it should be Church's theorem (1936), not Gödel's theorem (1931).

Comment: @M.Lonardi Church's Corollary 

Comment: @NamdakTönpa interesting, does that DNF solver get used a lot?

Comment: E.g. with multidimensional cubes.

Comment: @NamdakTönpa maybe write another answer about this? I know nothing

Comment: No, this answer is fine! If you want you can extend your answer with info about DNF solvers in modern provers. DNF is cool because it is studied in first year, so theorethical prerequisites are minimal.

Answer (score 7):

As an addition: proof *checking* (rather than search) already can be very hard. For instance, proof checking in type theory relies on conversion checking, which itself needs to evaluate arbitrary functions definable in the system. In something as expressive as CIC, this in theory has an extremely high complexity. In fact, one of the biggest known integer ([Loader’s number](https://googology.fandom.com/wiki/Loader%27s_number)) is linked to the size of functions definable in the Calculus of Constructions.